# How to configure nis client in irix

Tags: irix

Can anyone please let me know how to configure `nis` client in `irix` box.

How can I check whether `nis` package is installed or not in `irix`?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if **NIS** is installed using the:

[IRIX inst command](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/a_man/cat1/inst.z)

If NIS is already installed you should issue the command:

```
/etc/chkconfig yp on
```

to enable the **NIS** service and edit:

```
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

using any standard editor.

A network restart or system reboot will activate **NIS** for you.

Just check if your configuration is fine with

```
ypwhich
```

More information on :

[IRIX NIS configuration manual](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi/0650/bks/SGI_Admin/books/NIS_AG/sgi_html/ch04.html#LE41506-PARENT)